# Tried to live the server using ngrok but ending up getting error

Tags: django, ngrok

i have created a django crud application website and i want to live it using ngrok server once i tried to login using the link the ngrok given im getting this error

[09/Jan/2024 13:21:36] "GET /static/img/login.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1543188
Forbidden (Origin checking failed - https://4407-2001-d08-2901-3214-a5a4-7e36-5645-47c1.ngrok-free.app does not match any trusted origins.): /login/ , i have put the link on allowed host and CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer i need to put
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://*.ngrok.io",
"the website link from ngrok",]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think this will be to do with your settings.py Have you set the following:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['4407-2001-d08-2901-3214-a5a4-7e36-5645-47c1.ngrok-free.app', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

You need to ensure that ngrok.io is trusted for certificate validation. Also clear your browser cache.

let me know if this helps :)

andrewbyteforge

Comment: I have allowed the link on ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 
                 '127.0.0.1', 
                 '4407-2001-d08-2901-3214-a5a4-7e36-5645-47c1.ngrok-free.app',]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://4407-2001-d08-2901-3214-a5a4-7e36-5645-47c1.ngrok-free.app' i still can't seems to use it

Comment: Is it still the same error ?

Or a different one after adding those ?

Comment: still same error